# How to read AzureDevOps workitems using tools like LogicApps etc.?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I have 20 million workitems in my ADO(DevOps) and I am wondering the technology to read the workitems. right now I am able to pull the ADO workitems using Azure LogicApp but in logicApps I am able to pull only 1000 records. Is there way/tool available to read workitems ?

PS: I know we can use the REST Api to pull the workitems using batch but customer is not interested in coding.. any suggestions ?

Comment: How do you get the work items in the logic app?

Comment: Why do you want to read work items in  external tools?Is it because you have other needs?  If you just read the work item, you can do it in Azure devops.

Comment: Having 20 million workitems does not sound realistic to me. While query results are limited to 20.000 workitems, you are not even able to count them in Azure DevOps. Reference to limits in Azure DevOps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/user-guide/service-limits?view=azure-devops

Comment: @user3240560 Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue? If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0):

For your issue, as R Pelzer mentioned in the comment: The query results supported by azure devops are limited to 20,000.

[image]

So if you have 20 million work items, it’s currently not supported to query them all.

If you need to read more work items,you could add your request for this feature on our [UserVoice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) site, which is our main forum for product suggestions.You can vote and comment there to increase priority. Our PM and product team will kindly review your suggestion.
[image]